# SharePoint Refiner webpart only showing one filter item instead of three

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part, search, search-results

I am building an out of the box SharePoint search. The basic search works just fine.

I have created a SharePoint list and added a metadata column which is tied to the TermStore and ran the full crawl. All looks good till this point.

The problem is, I have added a Refiner web part which only shows one refiner item at a time ( either Samsung, Apple or HTC) depending on what I type in the searchbox as shown in the screenshots below.

I would like the Refiner to display all the three refiners at all times for users to select and filter their search results.

As you can see below the Refiner webpart only show the filter value that is typed in the searchbox:
[image]

and when I enter samsung, this is what I get:
[image]

Here is my List, with 'MyMobilePhone' column as the metadata column type: 
[image]

The metadata type column definition is shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

My Refiner configuration is as follows:
[image]

The Term Store can also be seen in the screenshot below: 
[image]

Please reply if there is something I need to do to fix my refiners to show all the filters options for users to select ( e.g. HTC, Apple, Samsung).

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

The refiner values will be pulled out of the current search results. They are not static. The behavior what you are seeing is expected result for me.

If you would like to see all 3 refiner values under "**AK Phones**" type something which is common for all the items (**phones**) in your list so that results will have all items and refiners will get all 3 terms.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you for the response, how can I make the filter values (HTC, Apple, Samsung) in the refiner webpart show at all times (not just based on what is typed in the searchbox). How can I do that? shall I use 'Taxonomy Refinement Panel' wepart or something?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar to this as you can see on the filter values on the left hand side of this page in this screenshot:http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-66-12/2605.CamerasFabrikam.png how shall we configure the webpart?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

In your Refinement web part, go to configure it once more and on the option "Display Template", there should be one template called "Multie-Value Refinement Item.

Select it and save the page, now you should be able to select multiple values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply user19952. When I choose the 'Multi-value Refinement item' I get something like this as shown in the screenshot here: http://tinypic.com/r/2ep7o81/8

What I am looking for is for the refiner webpart to show all the three filters values (Apple, Samsung, HTC) at all times for users to select.

Comment: The only refiner values that show are the ones in the result set. If you want to see all three search for "Product*"

Comment: Just like Matthew and Naveen said, this is the expected behaviour and how the search works.

Comment: that you for the response Matthew, how can I make the filter values in the refiner web part show all values (eg.Apple, HTC, Samsung)? or do i use the 'Taxonomy Refinement Panel' web part. All I am trying to do is achieve something like this: http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-66-12/2605.CamerasFabrikam.png

Comment: and the site type I am using is 'Publishing Site', I am able to add the 'Taxonomy Refinement Panel' webpart but can't make the refiners to work/show the values

Answer (score 0):

Refiners are connected with displayed results. And even when you show all hidden options from refiner, you will get 0 results if you click them. This is because refiner is a concatenation of "Search Query" AND "Refiner value".

I guess that you need new box with links only to "Refiner value". You can do this with Search Navigation webpart or create new Refiner Display Template and then change it to display all possible options with new links.